# JQuery slideUp horizontal menu instead of slideDown

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I have this menu :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function() {
    $("#menu").find("li").each(function() {
     if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {
      $(this).mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown(); 
      }); 
      $(this).mouseleave(function() {  
       $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();  
      });
     }
    });
   });
  </script>
  <style>
   #menu {
    display:block;
    margin:120px auto 20px;
    border:1px solid #222;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#6a6a6a;
    font:16px Tahoma, Sans-serif;
   }  
   #menu ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
   }  
   #menu li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
   }  
   #menu ul:after {
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
   }  
   #menu li a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    border-left:1px solid #999;
    border-right:1px solid #222;
    color:#eee;
    text-decoration:none;
   }  
   #menu li a:focus {
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:underline;
   }  
   #menu li:first-child a {
    border-left:none;
   }  
   #menu li.last a {
    border-right:none;
   }  
   #menu a span {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    margin-left:5px;
   }  
   #menu ul ul {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    background:#6a6a6a;
   }  
   #menu ul ul li {
    float:none;
   }  
   #menu ul ul a {
    padding:5px 10px;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
    font-size:14px;
   }

   a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="menu">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a>Item1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a>Item2</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">item2-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item2-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item2-3</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   <li>
    <a>Item3</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">item3-1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">item3-2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">item3-3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a>Item4</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <body>
<html>
```

It slides down when the cursor is over a `li` that contains a `ul`.

I want the submenu to slide up above the horizontal menu instead of sliding down under.

How can I achieve this ?

Thank you!

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LDQfW/8/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#menu ul ul {
    bottom:38px;
}
```

setting the bottom of the nested lists does the trick

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is, but you should be able to reduce your code down to this using a more complex selector:

```
$("#menu > ul > li:has(ul)").mouseenter(function() { 
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();  
}).mouseleave(function() {  
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();  
});
```

**EDIT:** I see, you want the physical direction of the menu to go up instead of down. To do this, your menus will need to be absolutely positioned at the bottom. Then a height change will make them go up.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BKLjs/

```
#menu ul ul {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom: 40px;
    background:#6a6a6a;
}
```

Here's a little further code reduction: http://jsfiddle.net/BKLjs/2/

```
$("#menu > ul > li:has(ul)").hover(function(e) { 
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true)['slide' + (e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 'Down' : 'Up')]();  
});
```

Comment: +1 you got it just a few seconds later, so this definitely was not plagiarism :)

Comment: Thanks @karim79. The issue didn't click for me at first. Getting late. :o)

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/LDQfW/10/

note: uses jquery UI:

```
.show("slide", { direction: "down" });
.hide("slide", { direction: "up" });
```